# Nutch says No URLs to fetch - check your seed list and URL filters

Tags: nutch

~/runtime/local/bin/urls/seed.txt >>

```
http://nutch.apache.org/
```

~/runtime/local/conf/nutch-site.xml >>

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

<!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->

<configuration>
    <property>
            <name>http.agent.name</name>
            <value>My Nutch Spider</value>
    </property>

    <property>
            <name>http.timeout</name>
            <value>99999999</value>
            <description></description>
    </property>

    <property>
            <value>protocol-file|protocol-httpclient|urlfilter-regex|parse-(html|tika)|index-(basic|anchor)|
            scoring-opic|urlnormalizer-(pass|regex|basic)|index-more
            </value>
            <description>Regular expression naming plugin directory names to
            include.  Any plugin not matching this expression is excluded.
            In any case you need at least include the nutch-extensionpoints plugin.
            </description>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

~/runtime/local/conf/regex-urlfilter.txt >>

```
# skip http: ftp: and mailto: urls
-^(http|ftp|mailto):

# skip image and other suffixes we can't yet parse
# for a more extensive coverage use the urlfilter-suffix plugin
-\.(gif|GIF|jpg|JPG|png|PNG|ico|ICO|css|CSS|sit|SIT|eps|EPS|wmf|WMF|zip|ZIP|ppt|PPT|mpg|MPG|xls|XLS|gz|GZ|rpm|RPM|tgz|TGZ|mov|MOV|exe|EXE|jpeg|JPEG|bmp|BMP|js|JS)$

# skip URLs containing certain characters as probable queries, etc.
-[?*!@=]

# skip URLs with slash-delimited segment that repeats 3+ times, to break loops
-.*(/[^/]+)/[^/]+\1/[^/]+\1/

# accept anything else
+^http://([a-z0-9\-A-Z]*\.)*nutch.apache.org/([a-z0-9\-A-Z]*\/)*
```

If I crawl, it says like this.

```
/home/apache-nutch-1.4-bin/runtime/local/bin
$ ./nutch crawl urls -dir newCrawl/ -depth 3 -topN 3
cygpath: can't convert empty path
solrUrl is not set, indexing will be skipped...
crawl started in: newCrawl
rootUrlDir = urls
threads = 10
depth = 3
solrUrl=null
topN = 3
Injector: starting at 2014-07-18 11:35:36
Injector: crawlDb: newCrawl/crawldb
Injector: urlDir: urls
Injector: Converting injected urls to crawl db entries.
Injector: Merging injected urls into crawl db.
Injector: finished at 2014-07-18 11:35:39, elapsed: 00:00:02
Generator: starting at 2014-07-18 11:35:39
Generator: Selecting best-scoring urls due for fetch.
Generator: filtering: true
Generator: normalizing: true
Generator: topN: 3
Generator: jobtracker is 'local', generating exactly one partition.
Generator: 0 records selected for fetching, exiting ...
Stopping at depth=0 - no more URLs to fetch.
No URLs to fetch - check your seed list and URL filters.
crawl finished: newCrawl
```

No matter what the web adresses are, it always says no urls to fetch.
I am struggling with this problem for 3 days. Please Help!!!!

Comment: Add some wikipedia page or a site with many links in seed.txt and try.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking at your regex-filter and I spotted a few glitches that you might think about giving a try. Since it won't fit well into the comment, I will post it here anyway even it might not be the complete answer.

1. Your customized regular expression `+^http://([a-z0-9\-A-Z]*\.)*nutch.apache.org/([a-z0-9\-A-Z]*\/)*` might be the problem. Nutch's regex-urlfilter sometimes can get really confusing and I would highly recommend you start with something that works for everyone, maybe `+^http://([a-z0-9]*\.)*nutch.apache.org/` from [Wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchTutorial) just to get started.
2. After the two steps above, and you are sure Nutch is working, then you can tweak the regex.

To test the regex, I found two ways to do it:

1. feed a list of URLs to be the seed. And inject them to a new database and see who has been injected or rejected. This doesn't really any coding.
2. You can set up [Nutch in Eclipse](http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/RunNutchInEclipse) and call the corresponding class to test it.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. But the first one was a typo. T.T

Comment: Hi.
I will also go with the options that above user has given.
I also suspect that problem is with the regex. so first remove it and try to run the program if it works then you can work on creating a correct regex for nutch site.
http://technical-fundas.blogspot.in/2014/06/how-to-configure-nutch-in-eclipse-for.html